# Android: AnimationDrawable squeezing my image

Tags: android, imageview, animationdrawable

I have this weird behavior that I cannot find a solution around...
This only happens in my emulator API Level 10, on my smartphone (Android 4.1) works fine.

I wrote a dynamic animation to show a rolling dice, where 10 random frames are chosen as the frames of the animation, with a duration of 50ms.

When I press the button, the animation run, but squeezed into zero height..... (You can still see some colors from the animating dice), the layout also get messed up.
This does not happen on my phone though.

[image: Before animation]
[image: During animation]

Here is the portion of the java code:

```
public void RollDice(View view) {
    int id=-1;
        AnimationDrawable diceAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();

        //create 10 random frames from dice1.jpg to dice6.jpg into diceAnimation
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            id=getResources().getIdentifier("dice"+String.valueOf(rng.nextInt(6)+1), "drawable", getPackageName());
            diceAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(id), 50);
        }

        //assigning and starting animation
        diceAnimation.setOneShot(true);
        dice.setImageDrawable(diceAnimation);
        diceAnimation.start();
}
```

and the portion of the xml:

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/Dice1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:contentDescription="@string/diceimage"
 android:src="@drawable/dice1" />
```

The button onclick call RollDice().

As final remark, IF I hardcode in ImageView, say android:layout_height="100dp", then the dice will show during animation, but streched into funny shape...

[image: During animation with 100dp]

I tried most scaling method, adjustviewbound etc with no luck...

Comment: any help out there? :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether your problem is solved or not.
But I would like to add the answer to this question.

You can try this :

Firstly , set you image view layout_width from match_parent to wrap_content.

Second make use of this below code so as to make the dice disappear completely :

frameAnimation.setVisibility(GONE);

Answer (score 0):

Might have an answer for your, try it out with caution, since I'm a beginner myself.

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());

ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_dice);
layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mParams);
layoutParams.width=120;
layoutParams.height=120;
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Applying that to your image will adjust the .xml on the fly, atleast it works for me when I'm grabbing alot of differently sized images from the web.